# Unable to create custom image VM's on Azure via powershell & portal

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

At the moment I'm trying to deploy a scale set based on a custom windows image created a while ago.

I know this has worked in the past, as our current production infrastructure is running using this exact image, but everytime I go to deploy this image as a vm using either the azure portal or powershell, I get the following error message:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:05:05 PM - Resource 
Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets 'test-scaleset' failed with 
message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
"details": [
  {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "message": "Disks or snapshot cannot be resized down."
  }
   ]
  }
}'
```

I created a new disk using the size A2_V2, and have proceeded to try to create a new VM using that image using the exact same size (A2_V2) all to no avail and with the same error message.

Does anyone have any idea what's happening here? I ensured the vm which was used to create the custom image had sysprep applied, with the generalized parameter set, and am coming at a loss as to why me, and multiple other members of the team are unable to create anything using custom images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you are use image(not disk) to create another new VM  then get this error?

Comment: Yes, sorry, we provisioned a VM which contains all the software we need, then turned it into a custom image for our future VMs. 

This custom image is stored on azure, and is used for each of our scale sets. In the past this has worked with no issues, but recently I'm getting the error above when trying to provision a new VM using that image.

Comment: That image(same image) works for VMSS but not work for your VM?

Comment: Yep, we deployed that scale set a few months ago, which is using that exact image. 

We're planning on upgrading the image, so I was attempting to deploy a few test VM's based on that image, but am now getting errors everytime I try to deploy a VM or VMSS using that image through the portal (Using the "Create VM" option when viewing the image) or powershell. It seems to have been a recent issue, as this hasn't happened before.

Comment: After that VM created(failed), can you find the new disk via your portal?

Comment: Afraid not, it gets as far as creating the NIC, IP and setting the NSG, but when it comes to provisioning the VM/Disk it gets the conflict and gives the same error. We're using managed disks.

Comment: Please create a support ticket via Azure portal, Microsoft teams will check it:)

Comment: Any update on this since we facing the same issue?

Comment: @MartinBrandl Apologies, I should have posted an update. 

We had to pay for support with microsoft, who in turn spent a week not knowing what the issue was. Eventually, they escalated it, and have found that it's a platform bug, whereby the managed disk is incorrectly recognised as 127GB in size, meaning there's a discrepancy when you create a new VM (as the new vm is 128gb in size).

The only way for us to fix it right now was to ask Microsoft to get their backend engineers to manually fix our pre-made images. 

The bug unfortunately still exists, and they have no ETA on a fix.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue where I wasn't able to create a VM based on a custom image. I also tried it with PowerShell:

[image]

However, I was able to fix it by recreating the image using the existing vhd, just go to the portal, click on "Create a ressource" and choose Image:

[image]

Then all you have to do is to select the vhd within your storage account:

[image]

Using the new image I was able to provision the VM.

Answer (score 1):

> Disks or snapshot cannot be resized down.

It is a known issue, please **increase** the size of that disk in Azure portal.

You can make it work by first de-attaching a Managed Disk, update the size and then attach it back to the VM.

More information about it, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/andyjballgit/AndysPowershell/blob/master/PowerShellModuleProject1/Public/Update-CVAzureRMDiskAttached.ps1).